# Apply changed language to localized strings

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, localization

I am having trouble applying changes to localized strings after switching language. Is there a way to see the change after setting language to UserDefaults? I found online, that to see the change you have to reset the app. How can I achieve this?

This is the function to change the language:

```
enum Language: String {
    case en, uk, ru
}
func switchLanguage(to language: Language) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set([language.rawValue], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
    }
```

This is the View, where you change the language.

```
import SwiftUI

struct LanguageView: View {
    @Injected private var userDefaultsManager: UserDefaultsManaging
    @State var isDialogDisplayed = false
    @State private var showingAlert = false
    @State var selected: Language?
    @State var original: Language?
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            AppBackground()
            List {
                Section(LocalizedStringKey("language")) {
                    languageButton(to: .en)
                    languageButton(to: .ru)
                    languageButton(to: .uk)
                }
            }
            .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
        }
        .alert(LocalizedStringKey("change_language_message"), isPresented: $showingAlert) {
            Button(LocalizedStringKey("choose")) {
                // TODO: Restart the app
                userDefaultsManager.switchLanguage(to: selected ?? .en)
            }
            Button(LocalizedStringKey("cancel"), role: .cancel) {
                withAnimation(.easeIn) {
                    selected = original ?? .en
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(LocalizedStringKey("change_language"))
        .onAppear {
            self.original = userDefaultsManager.getLanguage()
            self.selected = userDefaultsManager.getLanguage()
        }
    }
    @ViewBuilder func languageButton(to language: Language) -> some View {
        let languageName: LocalizedStringKey = {
            switch language {
            case .en:
                return .init("english")
            case .uk:
                return .init("ukraine")
            case .ru:
                return .init("russian")
            }
        }()
        Button {
            withAnimation(.easeIn) {
                if selected != language {
                    selected = language
                    showingAlert = true
                }
            }
        } label: {
            HStack {
                Text(languageName)
                if selected == language {
                    Spacer()
                    Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                }
            }
            .foregroundColor(.jmkBlue)
            .fontWeight(selected == language ? .semibold : .regular)
        }
        
    }
}
```

I expected the changes will be seen in no time.

Comment: In general I would advise against providing language switching settings in your app. iOS already provides the ability for the user to select a language, either for their device or for a specific app in the device settings.

Comment: Agreed. Unfortunately it is an app requirement

Answer (score 0):

I do not remember a SwiftUI syntax.

But the main idea is:

1. create a provider that indicates your View that she needs to redraw on language changing
2. select a different localization file. You can look here in the .stencil file. https://github.com/idapgroup/xcode-localization-parser